# How to change BASH "editing-mode vi" shortcuts?

Tags: linux, bash, keyboard-shortcuts, vi, readline

I'm trying to change my bash vi mode keys to enter and exit insert mode, I would like to set these shortcuts:

- Ctrl-\ : Enter moviment mode
- Alt-\ : Enter insert mode

how can I do that? I'm trying editing it to my .inputrc and/or .bashrc without success.

.inputrc:

```
set echo-control-characters off
#want vi to be the default editor for readline                      
set editing-mode vi                                            
set completion-ignore-case On
echo "mode: $mode"
# vi settings                                         
$if mode=vi
    #"\C-l":clear-screen
    #"\C-p":history-search-backward
    "\C-\":vi-movement-mode
    #set keymap vi-insert
    #"jj":vi-movement-mode
    "\M-\":vi-insertion-mode
$endif
```

then I'm trying to sourcing it:

```
maiko.costa@PEDCWB033:~$ source .inputrc 
mode: =vi
mode=vi: command not found
```

what it's wrong with my $if ? Below my current bash version.

```
maiko.costa@PEDCWB033:~$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.1.5(1)-release
```

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$if mode=vi` conditional looks correct.

Read .inputrc into bash with:

```
bind -f ~/.inputrc
```

To read the bash help for `bind`:

```
help bind
```

AFAIU, `echo` is not a valid `inputrc` command.

Here are the Bash readline docs: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Readline-Init-File